# How to access Querydict to list of send AJAX on django

Tags: python, django

I have this AJAX

```
function AjaxContact(Jsonmodel) {

model = Jsonmodel;
$.ajax({
    url: "/api/contact",
    datatype: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(model) ,
    success: function (data) {
        $(".seccuess").html(data).show();
        $("#firstname").val("");
        $("#lastname").val("");
        $("#connect").val("");
        $("#decreption").val("");
    },
```

while run this code i getting values like object. How to get values like dictionary or list of dictionaries

view.py

```
   GetdicJSON = request.POST
```

Output :

```
<QueryDict: {u'[{"Fname":"asda","Lname":"asd","Connection":"123123","Decreption":"asdas"}]': [u'']}>
```

Thanks

Comment: thanks, output :{u'[{"Fname":"asd","Lname":"asda","Connection":"2313","Decreption":"asdad"}]': u''}
do you have idea for access to Fname or Lname ?

Comment: you passed values in an incorrect way..

Comment: `re.search(r'"Fname"\s*:\s*"([^"]*)', d.keys()[0]).group(1)`, d means `GetdicJSON.dict()`

Comment: what your idea for pass values? there is best way ?

Answer (score 0):

Since the values passed turned into dictionary keys, you have to use string funcs in-order to pass the string or use  `literal_eval` to turn string to python data types (ie, dict, list, etc)

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> GetdicJSON = request.POST
>>> d = GetdicJSON.dict()
>>> literal_eval(d.keys()[0])[0]['Fname']
'asd'
>>> key = literal_eval(d.keys()[0])[0]
>>> key['Lname']
'asda'
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, I suggest you to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: Thanks, if i use list what?
<QueryDict: {u'[{"Fname":"saad","Lname":"asda","Connection":"1231","Decreption":"sadasd"},{"Fname":"saad","Lname":"asda","Connection":"12321","Decreption":"sdasd"}]': [u'']}>